# How to read R F-test results?

Tags: variance, p-value, f-test, nonparametric

[image]

I am trying to check that data adhere to the assumption of equal variance, so i can use a parametric test. But i do not know how to interpret the results of the Ftest.

Comment: I would recommend to read a stats 101 book and a R book, the question is too broad. which number you do not understand?

Comment: There are other ways of doing this which are often thought better like Levene's test or the Fligner-Killeen test.

Answer (score 3):

Well, just like most other statistical tests, look at the p-value and as its value is 0.3569, it is much higher than your alpha of 0.05 and so you do not have enough evidence to reject your null hypothesis, so that means you can assume that the variances are equal.

I hope that was what you were in fact looking for.